# Package datatool Error: Can't assign \company : there is no key `*' in data base `*'

Tags: tables, datatool, csv

Hy, i'm having problem with the `\DTLforeach` in my table. LaTeX returns the following error:

> Package datatool Error: Can't assign \company : there is no key `Company' in data base`produtosAloe'. ...\products & \website & \address\ \hline }

My entire code is above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}/


\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{produtosAloe}{../EstudoMercado.csv}
\title{Estudo de mercado}
\author{Glauco Goebel Tirollo}
\date{09 de Novembro de 2017}
\newcommand{\av}{\textit{Aloe Vera}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage

%\input{EstudoMercado.tex}
\section{Análise de Mercado}

A \av é uma planta com diversas aplicações medicinais e cosméticas, devido ao seu auto teor de princípios ativos. Para entender a vasta gama de utilizações da planta foi realizada uma busca das principais empresas que atuam no setor e os produtos que comercializam.

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    \DTLforeach*{produtosAloe}{\company=Company,\address=Address,\description=Description,\products=Products,\website=Website}
    {\company & \description & \products & \website & \address\\ \hline }

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

My CSV file is:

```
Company;Address;Description;Products;Website
Natier;Buenos Aires, Argentina;A Natier é uma empresa de produtos naturais, entre eles a babosa. A empresa possui uma variedade muito grande de produtos, com loja online e pontos físicos espalhados pela argentina.;Liofilizado;https://www.tiendanatier.com.ar
Natier;;;Suco Natural;
aloe explotaciones;Andalucía, Espanha;Grupo dedicado ao cultivo e produção de Aloe Vera ecológico e seus derivados. Seus produtos seguem os padrões de qualidade ditados pela União Européia. ;Plantas, folhas, gel, suco e liofilizados.;aloeexplotaciones.com
alibaba;china;;Aloe Vera liofilizada pó;https://spanish.alibaba.com
Veracetis;Madrid, Espanha;"Veracetis é uma empresa de base tecnológica, surgida na Universidade de Alcalá, e apresenta um novo conceito de produtos de consumos obtidos a partir de extratos vegetais bem como a  aplicação destes extratos em diversos setores.
Possuem produção totalmente nacional, e é a primeira empresa europeia com registro sanitário e registro de agricultura ecológica.
Possui um forte centro de PD\&I, que possui mais de 20 anos de experiência.";Suco, óleo, extrato seco, azeite, cápsulas, etc.;http://www.veracetics.es
the body shop;mundial;Empresa originalmente britânica, atualmente possui 160 lojas espalhadas por todo o mundo. Possui uma gama enorme de produtos na área de saúde, higiene e bem estar. ;Tônico calmante facial, Creme hidratante, espuma de limpeza facial, loção, sabão, creme de barbear, creme pós barba, chá de banho, esfoliantes, entre outros produtos.;https://www.thebodyshop.com
the face shop;Coréia;Empresa originalmente coreana, atualmente possui mais de 2600 lojas em 29 países ao redor do mundo. Possuem uma grande variedade de artigos de beleza baseados em principios ativos de plantas.;Sabonete líquido, máscara facial, gel calmante. ;https://thefaceshop.ca/
neutrogena;Los Angeles, Califórnia, EUA;neutrogena é uma marca norte-americana que inclui produtos faciais, para a pele, para os cabelos e colorações. Em 1994, foi comprada pela Johnson \& Johnson. Seus produtos são vendidos internacionalmente.;gel para acne, ;www.neutrogena.com.br
forever living;Madrid, Espanha;;sunscreen;foreverliving.com
Aloe Vera ESI;Itália;ESI é uma companhia especializada no desenvolvimento de produtos herbais, nutraceuticos e compelementos dietéticos e nutricionais. Fundada em 1975.;Sucos, suplementos alimentares.;www.esi.it
MexiAloe;Santa Bárbara, Campeche, México;A MexiAloe é a empres líder em produção e processamento de AloeVera na América Latina com certificação orgânica. Fundada em 1989, supre as indústrias do setor cosmético, farmacêutico e alimentício de todo o mundo.;gel concentrado, gel da folha toda, folhas, aloe vera spraydried, aloe vera liofilizada, ;http://www.mexialoelabs.com/
```

Comment: The standard separator in a CSV (= "Comma Separated Values" ) is unsurprisingly, the comma, (`,`) but your CSV file is separated by the semicolon (`;`).  So use `\DTLsetseparator{;}` to change the separator.

Comment: I did what you said, I don't know why excel did this to me... haha.
But the error continues, and now LaTeX sais: 
`Argument of \@dtl@qlopoff has an extra }. ...loaddb{produtosAloe}{../EstudoMercado.csv}`

Comment: If you have multiline cells CSV files you need to use [`datatooltk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk) as `\DTLloaddb` doesn't support it.